# Is there a way to make the text smaller inside a default font setting?

Tags: spacing, width

so I've written one document using the default margin settings and another using different margin settings(much wider). I needed to compile both documents so there's an obvious issue now. Let me show you what I mean:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amsfonts, graphicx, verbatim, amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{setspace}% if you must (for double spacing thesis)
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}
Computation of the Inverse Fourier transform from definition 3.1.3:
\[
f_{(0,0,0)} = \frac{1}{8}[f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}] = f_{(0,0,0)}
\]
\[
f_{(0,0,1)} = \frac{1}{8}[f_{(0,0,1)}+f_{(0,0,1)}+f_{(0,0,1)}+f_{(0,0,1)}-f_{(0,0,1)}\cdot {(-1)}-f_{(0,0,1)}\cdot {(-1)}-f_{(0,0,1)}\cdot {(-1)}-f_{(0,0,1)}\cdot {(-1)}] = f_{(0,0,1)}
\]
\[
f_{(0,1,0)} = \frac{1}{8}[f_{(0,1,0)}+f_{(0,1,0)}-f_{(0,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(0,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(0,1,0)}+f_{(0,1,0)}-f_{(0,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(0,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}] = f_{(0,1,0)}
\]
\[
f_{(0,1,1)} = \frac{1}{8}[f_{(0,1,1)}+f_{(0,1,1)}-f_{(0,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(0,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(0,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(0,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(0,1,1)}+f_{(0,1,1)}] = f_{(0,1,1)}
\]
\[
f_{(1,0,0)} = \frac{1}{8}[f_{(1,0,0)}-f_{(1,0,0)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,0)}-f_{(1,0,0)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,0)}-f_{(1,0,0)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,0)}-f_{(1,0,0)}\cdot{(-1)}] = f_{(1,0,0)}
\]
\[
f_{(1,0,1)} = \frac{1}{8}[f_{(1,0,1)}-f_{(1,0,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,1)}-f_{(1,0,1)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(1,0,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,1)}-f_{(1,0,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,1)}] = f_{(1,0,1)}
\]
\[
f_{(1,1,0)} = \frac{1}{8}[f_{(1,1,0)}-f_{(1,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(1,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,1,0)}+f_{(1,1,0)}-f_{(1,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(1,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,1,0)}] = f_{(1,1,0)}
\]
\[
f_{(1,1,1)} = \frac{1}{8}[f_{(1,1,1)}-f_{(1,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(1,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,1,1)}-f_{(1,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,1,1)}+f_{(1,1,1)}-f_{(1,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}] = f_{(1,1,1)}
\]
\end{document}
```

I want to use the default margins which means making the code above font smaller or are there better solutions?

Thank you.

***EDIT***: I have rechecked the output and making the font smaller wont be useful. I think I should break the line using align but I don't know how to use it properly.

```
\begin{align*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    \cline{1-9}
   $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$\\
    $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$\\
    $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$\\
    $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$\\
    $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$\\
    $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$\\
    $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,0,0)$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}

The character table:

\begin{align*}
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{c | c c c c c c c c }
  +  & $(0,0,0)$ & $(0,0,1)$ & $(0,1,0)$ & $(0,1,1)$ & $(1,0,0)$ & $(1,0,1)$ & $(1,1,0)$ & $(1,1,1)$\\
    \cline{1-9}
    $\chi_{(0,0,0)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,0,1)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,1,0)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(0,1,1)}$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,0,0)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,0,1)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,1,0)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$\\
    $\chi_{(1,1,1)}$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $-1$ & $1$ & $1$ & $-1$\\
\end{tabular}
\end{align*}
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand. What's it with the *two* documents you wrote? I only see one. You can change the fontsize e.g. with `\footnotesize`, but that's probably not what you're asking, is it?

Comment: You should not change the font sizes, you are already using `amsmath`, so why aren't you using the environments from it? I'd use `align*` and introduce line breaks on each of the original lines

Comment: @daleif so it almost fits the default margins but it is off by a word or two so I don't want to break the line as it wouldn't look as neat. Ok I rechecked, its off by quite a lot, not what I aforementioned.

Comment: For me those lines as off my up to 150pt. Remember, this is not about what is neat, it is about readability, consistency and good design. Changing the font size because something does not fit, or does not look neat, is not a good design.

Comment: For example I have an 8x8 table which also exceeds the default margin, I don't what would be considered good design as breaking a table would be quite abnormal! so I am stuck because everything else is consistent, I'd appreciate if you could help!

Comment: Regarding tables, quoting Robert Bringhurst (author of the Elements of Typographic style): "Tables are notoriously time-consuming
    to typeset, but the problems posed are often editorial as much as
    typographic. If the table is not planned in a readable form to
    begin with, the typographer can render it readable only by
    rewriting or redesigning it from scratch."

Comment: Meaning, for tables, just throwing data at a tables does not make it a good table. It needs thought and more often than not, redesign, fx moving common elements to table notes etc.

Comment: This is where I lack experience, should I say no experience at all. I'd appreciate a starting point since I've just recently started using LaTex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is probably how I'd typeset it. Note, there is a thought behind where each line is broken, highlighting the ending `=f...`

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
Computation of the Inverse Fourier transform from definition 3.1.3:
\begin{align*}
f_{(0,0,0)} &= \frac{1}{8}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl[&f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}
  \\
  &+f_{(0,0,0)}
  +f_{(0,0,0)}
  +f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}+f_{(0,0,0)}\bigr]
  = f_{(0,0,0)}
\end{aligned}
\\
f_{(0,0,1)} &= \frac{1}{8}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl[&f_{(0,0,1)}+f_{(0,0,1)}+f_{(0,0,1)}+f_{(0,0,1)}-f_{(0,0,1)}\cdot
  {(-1)}\\
  &-f_{(0,0,1)}\cdot {(-1)}-f_{(0,0,1)}\cdot
  {(-1)}-f_{(0,0,1)}\cdot {(-1)}\bigr] = f_{(0,0,1)}
\end{aligned}
\\
f_{(0,1,0)} &= \frac{1}{8}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl[&f_{(0,1,0)}+f_{(0,1,0)}-f_{(0,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(0,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}
  \\
  &+f_{(0,1,0)}
  +f_{(0,1,0)}-f_{(0,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(0,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}\bigr] =
  f_{(0,1,0)}
\end{aligned}
\\
f_{(0,1,1)} &= \frac{1}{8}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl[&f_{(0,1,1)}+f_{(0,1,1)}-f_{(0,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(0,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}
  \\
  &-f_{(0,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}
  -f_{(0,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(0,1,1)}+f_{(0,1,1)}\bigr]
  = f_{(0,1,1)}
\end{aligned}
\\
f_{(1,0,0)} &= \frac{1}{8}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl[&f_{(1,0,0)}-f_{(1,0,0)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,0)}-f_{(1,0,0)}\cdot{(-1)}
  \\
  &+f_{(1,0,0)}
  -f_{(1,0,0)}\cdot{(-1)}
  +f_{(1,0,0)}-f_{(1,0,0)}\cdot{(-1)}\bigr]
  = f_{(1,0,0)}
\end{aligned}
\\
f_{(1,0,1)} &= \frac{1}{8}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl[&f_{(1,0,1)}-f_{(1,0,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,1)}-f_{(1,0,1)}\cdot{(-1)}
  \\
  &-f_{(1,0,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,1)}-f_{(1,0,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,0,1)}\bigr]
  = f_{(1,0,1)}
\end{aligned}
\\
f_{(1,1,0)} &= \frac{1}{8}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl[&f_{(1,1,0)}-f_{(1,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(1,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,1,0)}
  \\
  &+f_{(1,1,0)}
  -f_{(1,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(1,1,0)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,1,0)}\bigr]
  = f_{(1,1,0)}
\end{aligned}
\\
f_{(1,1,1)} &= \frac{1}{8}
\begin{aligned}[t]
  \bigl[&f_{(1,1,1)}-f_{(1,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}-f_{(1,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}+f_{(1,1,1)}
  \\
  &
  -f_{(1,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}
  +f_{(1,1,1)}+f_{(1,1,1)}-f_{(1,1,1)}\cdot{(-1)}\bigr]
  = f_{(1,1,1)}
\end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for the solution provided. +1

Comment: Now If I may ask, how can I apply a similar trick to the tables in the question?

Comment: Please post another question instead of highjacking, and note that tabulars does not belong in math mode, use array instead.